# What tools can I use for PCB making at home?

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication

I want to create my own PCBs for prototyping and hobby purposes. I have experimented with buying them in China, which is cheap but not very fast. No idea on the quality either, but for $5 for 5 boards, you can never go wrong.

I have checked local manufacturers, but a prototype board easily goes for €75, which is too much for experimenting.

So I was wondering what would be a solution to make them at home. When researching, I find some CNC machines but I fail to understand how I could make PCB with that.

I thought perhaps some kind of 3D printer could do the trick, but no idea where I could find that or if it even exists.

I am fine with spending money, but the price per board should be low and the process should be easy.

Comment: DIY PCBs at home and "process should be easy" is kinda self excluding. You are often pretty limited in terms of track width/size/mask/layers and so on so.. Taking a week or so to get PCBs from China is not that bad. Alternatively, you could try more point to point construction, etc. I've personally tried etching, machining, thermal and photo transfer, pens, etc etc and I've never done any PCBs at home after I started having them made by a proper fab house.

Comment: FWIW, I've gotten 4 layer boards from China to the USA in 6 calendar days.  Keeping board sizes compact, using common colors, etc tends to lead to fast turn around times.  Do you need faster than that?  Going to be a fair amount of work.

Comment: Making boards at home with any quality is pretty much limited to single sided.  Double sided can be done, but you need a method for aligning and connecting the vias.  Through hole parts usually does that for pads.  But SMT boards and tiny vias will be tough.

Comment: I'm waiting on some boards from China, total $25 USD for 10 pieces, including shipping. They were ordered Sunday morning Shenzhen time. It's Thursday. They might be here later today or tomorrow. I've made PCBs myself using a bunch of different methods, it's messy, time consuming & the resulting quality is generally inferior to vastly inferior to factory made boards. Of course you can invest in all the equipment & make nice boards, but beyond single-sided it become not just expensive, but *very* expensive & tricky to deal with the chemicals- their sourcing, their  maintenance, & their disposal.

Comment: As a poor student, I used to make my own single-sided (and occasionally double-sided) PCBs using PCB material with a photo-sensitive layer, high-resolution laser prints of the design on calc paper, a home-made UV exposure box, NaOH-containing drain cleaner for developing, and a mix of H2O2 and HCl for etching. Cheap and cheerful. Not contributing anything here, just being nostalgic. Now that factory-made small-series PCBs are affordable, I never consider making my own anymore.

Comment: Not to sound condescending, but have you tried googling? Because there are hundreds if not thousands websites and videos detailing all the methods available. If you do your research, however, you'd see that making your own PCBs is not that fast. You can easily waste a day if you want passable quality for high density  board. Proto boards are much faster but can get expensive. Ordering from China is slightly longer but much cheaper and good quality. What's left in the middle is not worth it, IMHO.

Comment: Having made PCBs at home, the quality you will get from China will make your homemade PCBs ashamed.

Comment: All of the above said, the CNC method you're asking about just takes a solid coated circuit board and cuts away the copper wherever you don't want it.  It has its challenges and high startup cost, but it's the lowest effort of the decently accurate home methods.  If you set up your jigs properly, double sided is no problem.  That said a board house board is still nicer.  Plated and filled vias give you a lot of options, not just a good connection, but they can be used for thermal control or used in excess to improve a multilayer circuit without a bunch of extra labor.

Comment: Note: "5 boards for $5" probably means the company is losing money on you, but they're doing it to bankrupt your local company so everyone will use them in the future...

Comment: I wouldn't even entertain the idea.  The chemicals used are very nasty.  If getting boards from China bothers you, Sunstone is a US based fabricator.    I've had great luck with them..   www.sunstone.com

Comment: If you sign up with a batch processing group price is decent and you can get 4 layer boards too.  Processing time is a bit long though because you have to wait for enough people to sign up.